# how to give current time and date to file name while exporting using ng-csv

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
<div class="col-md-1" ng-show="1==1">
            <img
                ng-csv="generateCSV()"
                filename="my.csv"
                src="../images/csv.png"
                style="height: 25px; width: 25px; cursor: pointer"/>
            <span>
                Export
            </span>
        </div>
```

How to give current time and date to the file name while exporting. I'm using ng-csv function of Angular JS to export JSON data as excel. Right now Im giving some default name to the exported CSV file,is it possible to give current date as file name? Using angular JS expressions or something like that?

Comment: When does file get downloaded ? On `click` ?

Comment: Yes,on click of the button

Answer (score 0):

You can create a date object in the controller, for example:

```
function Ctrl($scope)
{
    $scope.date = new Date();
}
```

and in the view:

```
<div class="col-md-1" ng-show="1==1">
            <img
                ng-csv="generateCSV()"
                filename="{{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}-my.csv"
                src="../images/csv.png"
                style="height: 25px; width: 25px; cursor: pointer"/>
            <span>
                Export
            </span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in html:

```
<div class="col-md-1" ng-show="1==1">
            <img
                ng-csv="generateCSV()"
                filename="{{$ctrl.getDatetime()}}.csv"
                src="../images/csv.png"
                style="height: 25px; width: 25px; cursor: pointer"/>
            <span>
                Export
            </span>
        </div>
```

in controller create this function:

```
getDatetime(){
return "On"+(new Date).getDay()+"/"+(new Date).getMonth()+"/"+(new Date).getFullYear()+"at"+(new Date).getHours()+":"+(new Date).getMinutes();
 }
```

Comment: please add more description regarding the answer.

Comment: You just need to create a function in your cotnroller.I update the code on top.